# Create a Tag and Merge with a branch SVN

Tags: svn

On my production i have this latest branch "`PROD_BRANCH_URL`".
For a change i  created a branch “`NEW_BRANCH_URL`” in which i do not have the changes of above branch. 
Now the issue is new branch does not contain the changes of the latest branch that is in the Production.

I want to create a tag from trunk and then merge changes from `NEW_BRANCH_URL` to the new tag.

Comment: What have you already tried? What's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, read the documentation on merging: [SVNBook | Basic Merging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html). And you haven't really described what's your task and what questions you have.

> For a change i created a branch “NEW_BRANCH_URL” in which i do not
>   have the changes of above branch. Now the issue is new branch does not
>   contain the changes of the latest branch that is in the Production.

So? Create a branch that contains the changes.

1. [Create a new branch out of `PROD_BRANCH_URL`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.using.html#svn.branchmerge.using.create) as `NEW_CORRECT_BRANCH`.
2. [Sync the changes from the trunk or `PROD_BRANCH_URL`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.stayinsync) depending on your requirements to `NEW_CORRECT_BRANCH`.
3. Make the changes to `NEW_CORRECT_BRANCH`.
4. Merge it with the trunk or branch you have to merge.

> I want to create a tag from trunk and then merge changes from
>   NEW_BRANCH_URL to the new tag.

That's a wrong idea. You should merge the changes to trunk first. After the merge you should make a new tag. Don't commit to tags as you were planning to.